# List of all third party classes called by a Java application

Tags: java

A legacy application uses several libraries as dependencies. I would like to know all the compile time and run time classes required by the application directly or transitively. The build tool being currently used is gradle.

List of dependencies is not the solution as some jars that are used are fat jars created by exploding third party jars and creating a single jar out of it.

Comment: You need to find out how those fat jars were built. One clue is looking at the modification (build) dates of the classes in the fat jars.

Comment: Check [Tattletale](https://docs.jboss.org/tattletale/userguide/1.2/en-US/html_single/). Also check ProGuard.